# TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Tags: python

say I have a dictionary i.e

```
dict = {'tommy' = '[[], []]'}
```

when I run the code below, it gives the error: `argument of type bool is not iterable`. I'm really stuck on this and would appreciate a solution. The code takes two inputs, the dict and a user. It's supposed to check if user is in dict - if it is, return the first element in the value. otherwise, return None.

```
def get_stuff(dict, user):
    if user in dict:
         return dict[user][0]
    return None
```

Comment: Show the full stacktrace and how you're using the function. The function looks fine, it must be the arguments you're passing in.

Comment: I get a syntax error on `{'tommy' = '[[], []]'}` in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: The dict should be: `dict = {'tommy' : [[], []]}` and not dict = `{'tommy' = '[[], []]'}`

Comment: Yes the dict shown is wrong, but it's not the only problem. A syntax error is not the cause of a bool being passed to the function.

Comment: Changing the dict and using @lafada response, the function worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Tico, @Tomi if you try `print dict` in function then you will get, you passed dict or bool.

Comment: I'm sorry. It should have been {'tommy' : [[], []]}. But I just figured out my error was in some latter part of my code. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

problem is

```
dict = {'tommy' = '[[], []]'}
```

you have to give it as

```
dict = {'tommy' = [[], []]}
```

dict with list as element

Comment: That's not the issue (though it would be an issue). The dict argument to the function is a bool for some reason.. the dict constructed in the question is a syntax error, and is probably just a copy/paste problem.

Comment: Correct , but he has to give detail :)